# Printing the first paragraph from infile to outfile

Tags: python

I have one file containing a speech, and have an empty output file. I am trying to print the first paragraph of the speech (read infile) and print it out to the outfile using if/else statement.

the program isn't bugging but its not outputting to my outfile.

```
file = open("/Users/newuser/Desktop/MLKspeech.txt", "r")
file2 = open("/Users/newuser/Desktop/mlkparagraph.txt", "w")

content = file.read()
for j in content:
    if (j == ""):
        continue
    elif (j == "\n"):
        file2.write(content)
   else:
       break
```

Comment: Yes, sorry I didn't want to flood you guys with extra content, but file1 is a speech from a famous speaker, file2 is an empty file, and content = file.read().

Answer (score 1):

Assuming paragraphs are separated by an empty line, you can iterate on the file line-by-line and write them to the new file, until an empty line is reached. An empty line can be discovered with [`str.isspace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isspace):

```py
with open("MLKspeech.txt") as in_file, open("mlkparagraph.txt", 'w') as out_file:
    for line in in_file:
        if line.isspace():
            break
        out_file.write(line)
```

Comment: awesome, thank you very much, i could also use == '\n' too instead of isspace():!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your paragraphs are separated with the '\t' character, you could try this:

```
with open('file1.txt', mode='rt') as file:
    breakpoint = file.read().find('\t')
    file.seek[0]
    with open('file2.txt', mode='wt') as file2:
        file2.write(file.read()[:breakpoint])
```

Comment: thank you for your quick answer! the speech does not have any tabs separating the paragraphs, only spaced in between the paragraphs, but i could just use, "\n" instead of tab.

Answer (score 0):

The goal is to capture the first few lines of your input file until you read an empty line (where there is either nothing or only a newline character). One way of doing that is to iterate through each line in the text with `f.readlines()` and store only the lines that you need in a list, breaking when you read an empty line:

```
content = []

with open('infile.txt') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        if line in ('', '\n'):
            break
        content.append(line)
```

You can then write each line to your output file:

```
with open('outfile.txt', 'w') as f:
    for line in content:
        f.write(line)
```